# Mysql IN operator with ifnull

Tags: mysql

I am doing reports and need to pass a list of comma seperated string to a column. That is easy I can just use the mysql IN operator. Only thing is the post variable may be NULL sometimes so how do I combine:

```
  where columnName in(ifnull($postVar,columnName))
```

if there is another way to accomplish this i am welcome to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

use a AND like this

```
 SELECT ......
 where columnName in($postVar)   // $postVar = "'joe','peter','paul'"
 AND columnName IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: can you post the value of postVar

Comment: I fixed the issue using php.